# Gallio TestDriven.Net testing problem

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mbunit, gallio, testdriven.net

I have a tdd system  , where I use Gallio 3.1 with TestDriven.Net .
I've downloaded the patches for them.

1) I'm getting this stack and the test wouldn't stop -
SRCSRV:  cmd /c svn.exe cat "http://mb-unit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v3.1/src/Gallio/Gallio/Framework/Pattern/PatternTestInstanceState.cs@2360" --non-interactive > "C:\DOCUME~1\tzvik\LOCALS~1\APPLIC~1\SOURCE~1\svn\branches\v3.1\src\Gallio\Gallio\Framework\Pattern\PatternTestInstanceState.cs\2360\patterntestinstancestate.cs"
         'svn.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
         operable program or batch file.
SRCSRV: Source server cannot retrieve the source code for file 'c:\RelEng\Projects\MbUnit v3.1\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Framework\Pattern\PatternTestInstanceState.cs' in module 'C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.
The thread 'Simple Test Driver' (0xb84) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ProcessInvocation.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Reports.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ProcessInvocation.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'vkcfotcv'
'ProcessInvocation.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll'
'ProcessInvocation.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.1'
'ProcessInvocation.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery'

after the last line it just haults in some loop that i can't understand.. 
how do i solve this?

2) I am getting some trial from Gallio to find some file that is missing ? 
 cmd /c svn.exe cat "http://mb-unit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/v3.1/src/Gallio/Gallio/Framework/Pattern/PatternTestInstanceState.cs@2360" --non-interactive > "C:\DOCUME~1\tzvik\LOCALS~1\APPLIC~1\SOURCE~1\svn\branches\v3.1\src\Gallio\Gallio\Framework\Pattern\PatternTestInstanceState.cs\2360\patterntestinstancestate.cs"
in a popup also sometimes..
anyone have some message like that or am i that "special"? 
thanks, people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "patches" for TDNet and Gallio?

This sounds like an installation problem.  You could try running "Gallio.Utility.exe VerifyInstallation" to confirm that.  If it returns errors then you can try uninstalling Gallio, deleting the Gallio program files directory and reinstalling.

As for the dialog box about "svn.exe", that's because you have Source Server support enabled in Visual Studio.  It's designed to let you debug into the Gallio source code if you have Subversion installed.  It can be very useful if you suspect there is a bug in the framework.

More information about debugging with symbols and source code: http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gallio:debugging_with_symbols_and_source_code